# SQL to count records that have no match in one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables:

surveys (date, location, kilometers) 
primary key: date + location 
     (one record per survey)

specimens (date, location, species) (zero or more records per survey date and location)

I want to find the count of surveys and the sum of kilometers surveyed where the specimens table contains no records for a particular species.  In other words the number of surveys where a particular species was NOT found.

The total number of surveys is:

```
select count(date) as surveys, sum(kilometers) as KM_surveyed 
from surveys;

 +---------+-------------+
 | surveys | KM_surveyed |
 +---------+-------------+
 |   20141 |    40673.59 |
 +---------+-------------+
```

Finding the number of surveys where no specimens were found is easy:

```
select count(s.date) as surveys, sum(s.kilometers) as KM_surveyed 
from surveys=s left join specimens=p 
on (s.date=p.date and s.location=p.location)
where p.date is null;

 +---------+-------------+
 | surveys | KM_surveyed |
 +---------+-------------+
 |    8820 |    15848.26 |
 +---------+-------------+
```

The total number of records in specimens is:

```
select count(*) from specimens;

+-----------+
|  count(*) |
+-----------+
|     51566 |
+-----------+
```

The correct number of Harbor Seals (HASE) found on all surveys is:

```
select count(*) from specimens where species = 'HASE';

 +-----------+
 | count(*)  |
 +-----------+
 |       662 |
 +-----------+
```

Finding the number of surveys where Harbor Seals (HASE) were found is not easy.
Since the specimens table typically contains multiple records per survey, this query returns not the number of surveys but the number of HASE specimens found:

```
select count(s.date), sum(s.kilometers) 
from surveys=s 
left join specimens=p on (s.date=p.date and s.location=p.location) 
where p.species = 'HASE';

 +---------+-------------+
 | surveys | KM_surveyed |
 +---------+-------------+
 |     662 |     2030.70 |  WRONG! that is number of specimens not surveys 
 +---------+-------------+
```

Finding the number of surveys where no Harbor Seals (HASE) were found is not easy either. This query returns not the number of surveys but the number of specimens found that were not Harbor Seals:

```
select count(s.date), sum(s.kilometers) 
from surveys=s 
left join specimens=p on (s.date=p.date and s.location=p.location) 
where p.species <> 'HASE' or p.date is null;`

 +---------+-------------+
 | surveys | KM_surveyed |
 +---------+-------------+
 |   50904 |   151310.49 | 
 +---------+-------------+
```

WRONG! 50904 = number of non HASE specimens

How do I construct queries to correctly count the number of surveys where Harbor Seals were found and the survey count when they were not found?

Comment: I guess distinct might be missing

Comment: It would be much easier if you would use a distinct primary key for a survey and a specimen other than the combination of date + location since you want to find the number of surveys where Harbour Seals are found/not found. Since your specimens table also use date + location you have to decide if it is a specific date or time you would consider a "location". This results in a more complex question/query than necessary.

Comment: What is this: `from surveys=s left join specimens=p`? You can't put `=` between the table name and alias.

Comment: Hmm.. I somehow can't find the difference between your first two queries.

Comment: I edited the post to show the correct second query.

Comment: Barmar:  Yes you can use an equals sign to define an alias.  I do it all the time.  It is just the same as saying "specimens as p".

Comment: @phper I can't find anything about it in the documentation. Is it archaic syntax that's accepted for backward compatibility?

Comment: First time I see this syntax for table aliasing. And it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `EXISTS` / `NOT EXISTS` subquery in the WHERE clause.

Surveys where `HASE` is found in `specimens` table:

```
select count(*), sum(s.kilometers)
from surveys s
where exists (
    select *
    from specimens p
    where s.date=p.date
      and s.location=p.location
      and p.species = 'HASE'
)
```

Surveys where `HASE` is not found in `specimens` table:

```
select count(*), sum(s.kilometers)
from surveys s
where not exists (
    select *
    from specimens p
    where s.date=p.date
      and s.location=p.location
      and p.species = 'HASE'
)
```

An alternative to the first query could be:

```
select count(*), sum(s.kilometers)
from (
    select distinct date, location
    from specimens
    where species = 'HASE'
) p
join surveys s using (date, location)
```

Depending on the data (if 'HASE' is a rare "species") it might be faster.

The probably best alternative for the second query is already posted by Barmar.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing a `LEFT JOIN` to find non-matching rows, you should put the criteria that shouldn't be matched into the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(s.kilometers)
FROM surveys AS s
LEFT JOIN specimens AS p ON s.date = p.date and s.location = p.location
    AND p.species = 'HASE'
WHERE p.date IS NULL
```

Comment: That would also be my choice for the "not found" query.

Answer (score 0):

Why do people find joins so hard?

Finding the number of surveys where Harbor Seals (HASE) were found:

```
select count(distinct concat(s.location, s.date))
from surveys s 
Inner join specimens p 
on (s.date=p.date and s.location=p.location) 
where p.species = 'HASE';
```

Finding the number of surveys where no Harbor Seals (HASE) were NOT found is simply the difference between the number of surveys (which you already have) and the value from above. Since both queries return a single row a cartesian product of the queries will give a value in a single ouput row, but just to be a bit different:

```
Select count(*), sum(kilometres)
From (
  Select kilometres
  From surveys s
  Left join specimens p 
  on (s.date=p.date and s.location=p.location) 
  and p.species = 'HASE'
  Where p.species is null
) As zero_surveys;
```

(There are several other ways to write the query above)

Comment: The "inner join" doesn't help.  The problem is that each specimen record matches a survey record and there are multiple specimens for many of the surveys so the same survey gets counted multiple times.  The query with inner join gets the same answer as the one with left join:  50904 surveys, which is impossible.

Comment: @phper Your LEFT JOIN is converted to an INNER JOIN by the optimizer. So your queries are essentially the same. Thus the same result.

Comment: Doh - having a blonde moment. fixed